# Academic dishonesty: Sending material to other group members?

Tags: ethics, university, plagiarism

To help with the rest of the members for the group assignment I sent some images of a guide on how to do academic research for assignments.

This ordinarily came from another unit of mine, which was composed by a librarian to help with an assignment in that unit.

The image includes the unit code for that unit and I’ve mentioned it to them that it came from another unit of mine and told them not to send it to others.

I’m very worried now. Is this considered to be academic dishonestly? It didn’t actually cross my mind until one of my friends told me.

Is the mere fact that I’ve sent material that came from another unit to group members who don’t study this unit considered to be academic dishonesty? Thanks!!!

Comment: By "unit" did you mean "class" or "section of a class"?

Comment: Well, it is not "academic dishonesty", at most it is "copyright violation". On the other hand, in many cases, students have easy access to course materials even if not taking the course (through library or by signing up and then not taking the course). No one is going to be able to claim that your sharing of a few pictures purely for academic purposes will economically harm the author of the work, so I do not think this is going to be an issue. Still, check the rules about this in your university and be better informed next time!

Comment: @G. Allen Unit as in a class/subject. That’s what we call it in my area.

Comment: @wimi thanks! Yep. I’ll have a relook. Although I’ve read it before, it’s been a few years and I don’t specifically some of the minor parts >.<